# Angular datatable looks too tight

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

Here is my code for my datatable. The columns too packed together, and it's hard to tell them apart. I tried to change the spacing, width of the columns in CSS, add a custom ngClass but nothing had worked. What should I do to fix this?

```
  <table id="order-information" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="order-table w-100-p mt-24">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="DeliveryNumber" >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngClass]="'w-75'">Tesellüm No</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="'w-75'">
                <div>{{row?.DeliveryNumber}}</div>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="StockIntegrationCode" >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngClass]="'w-75'">Stok Kodu</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="'w-75'"> {{row?.Product?.StockIntegrationCode}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="ProductName" >
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header [ngClass]="'w-100'">Stok Adı</th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" [ngClass]="'w-100'"> {{row?.Product?.ProductName}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="QuantityIn">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Miktar </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.QuantityIn}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="UnitTypeId">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Birim </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row?.UnitTypeId}} </td>
        </ng-container>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; let i = index"></tr>
    </table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to remove all width classes (w-100, w-75,...), and see how it looks.